# jQuery: Selecting the second element when selectors are same using :eq

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I have the following code. There are two svg elements with same selectors , and i'm trying to select all the elements.

When i use  selector `[inner-text='" + innerText + "'][depth='" + depth + "']` I will be able to access the first element. When i try to access the second element using `:eq(2)` it gives an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[inner-text='Exchanges data with'][depth='3']:eq(2)' is not a valid selector.` How can i access all the elements ( say loop over all the elements in case the selectors are same )

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
  var innerText = "Exchanges data with";
  var depth = "3";
  $( "#btn" ).click(function() {
     point1 = jQuery(d3.selectAll("[inner-text='" + innerText + "'][depth='" + depth + "']")[0]).attr('transform').toString();
    
    alert(point1);
    
    point2 = jQuery(d3.selectAll("[inner-text='" + innerText + "'][depth='" + depth + "']:eq(2)")[0]).attr('transform').toString();
    
  
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg>

  <g class="node" transform="translate(10,10)" inner-text="Exchanges data with" nodeid="4-3" parent-list="test asset 1" child-list="test asset 9-" parent-id="6-2" child-id="-3" has-child="true" depth="3">
    <circle r="4.5"></circle>
  </g>

  <g class="node" transform="translate(20,20)" inner-text="Exchanges data with" nodeid="2-3" parent-list="test asset 6" child-list="" parent-id="1-2" child-id="" has-child="true" depth="3">
    <circle r="4.5" style="stroke: rgb(141, 214, 223); fill: rgb(141, 214, 223);"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>


<button id="btn">Click Me </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the error because you tried to use a jQuery extension (`:eq`) in a `d4.selectAll` call. Since `:eq` is provided by jQuery, that won't work.

[`selectAll`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_selectAll) returns all matching elements, so

```
var points = d3.selectAll("[inner-text='" + innerText + "'][depth='" + depth + "']");
var point1 = jQuery(points[0][0]);
var point2 = jQuery(points[0][1]);
var transform1 = point1.attr('transform'); // No need for toString, it will always be a string
var transform2 = point2.attr('transform');
```

You can find out how many points there are from `points.length`; individual points are accessible with indexes `0` through `points.length - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:nth-child` instead of `:eq`, in this case.

Try below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
  var innerText = "Exchanges data with";
  var depth = "3";
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    point1 = jQuery(d3.selectAll("[inner-text='" + innerText + "'][depth='" + depth + "']")[0]).attr('transform').toString();

    alert(point1);

    point2 = jQuery(d3.selectAll("[inner-text='" + innerText + "'][depth='" + depth + "']:nth-child(2)")[0]).attr('transform').toString();
    
    alert(point2);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg>

  <g class="node" transform="translate(10,10)" inner-text="Exchanges data with" nodeid="4-3" parent-list="test asset 1" child-list="test asset 9-" parent-id="6-2" child-id="-3" has-child="true" depth="3">
    <circle r="4.5"></circle>
  </g>

  <g class="node" transform="translate(20,20)" inner-text="Exchanges data with" nodeid="2-3" parent-list="test asset 6" child-list="" parent-id="1-2" child-id="" has-child="true" depth="3">
    <circle r="4.5" style="stroke: rgb(141, 214, 223); fill: rgb(141, 214, 223);"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>


<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: `:eq` and `:nth-child` are **not**, at all, equivalent. `.foo:eq(2)` means "the third element with class `foo`", whereas `.foo:nth-child(3)` means "the third child, **if** it has class `foo`". Very, very different things.

Comment: *"You can use :nth-child instead of :eq, in this case."* Only if you assume that all of the siblings match the `inner-text` and `depth` filters, which is true in the very small data shown by the user, but is unreliable in the general case. `:nth-child` is just the wrong tool for this job.